# Plotting a piecewise regression line

Tags: r, data-visualization, regression

Is there a way of plotting the regression line of a piecewise model like this, other than using `lines` to plot each segment separately, or using `geom_smooth(aes(group=Ind), method="lm", fill=FALSE)` ?

```
m.sqft <- mean(sqft)
model <- lm(price~sqft+I((sqft-m.sqft)*Ind))
# sqft, price: continuous variables, Ind: if sqft>mean(sqft) then 1 else 0

plot(sqft,price)
abline(reg = model)
Warning message:
In abline(reg = model) :
  only using the first two of 3regression coefficients
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this easily is to predict from the model across the range of `sqft` and plot the predictions. There isn't a general way with `abline` or similar. You might also take a look at the **[segmented](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html)** package which will fit these models and provide the plotting infrastructure for you.

Doing this via predictions and base graphics. First, some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
sqft <- runif(100)
sqft <- ifelse((tmp <- sqft > mean(sqft)), 1, 0) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.5)
price <- 2 + 2.5 * sqft
price <- ifelse(tmp, price, 0) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.6)
DF <- data.frame(sqft = sqft, price = price,
                 Ind = ifelse(sqft > mean(sqft), 1, 0))
rm(price, sqft)
plot(price ~ sqft, data = DF)
```

Fit the model:

```
mod <- lm(price~sqft+I((sqft-mean(sqft))*Ind), data = DF)
```

Generate some data to predict for and predict:

```
m.sqft <- with(DF, mean(sqft))
pDF <- with(DF, data.frame(sqft = seq(min(sqft), max(sqft), length = 200)))
pDF <- within(pDF, Ind <- ifelse(sqft > m.sqft, 1, 0))
pDF <- within(pDF, price <- predict(mod, newdata = pDF))
```

Plot the regression lines:

```
ylim <- range(pDF$price, DF$price)
xlim <- range(pDF$sqft, DF$sqft)
plot(price ~ sqft, data = DF, ylim = ylim, xlim = xlim)
lines(price ~ sqft, data = pDF, subset = Ind > 0, col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(price ~ sqft, data = pDF, subset = Ind < 1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

You could code this up into a simple function - you only need the steps in the two preceding code chunks - which you can use in place of `abline`:

```
myabline <- function(model, data, ...) {
    m.sqft <- with(data, mean(sqft))
    pDF <- with(data, data.frame(sqft = seq(min(sqft), max(sqft),
                                            length = 200)))
    pDF <- within(pDF, Ind <- ifelse(sqft > m.sqft, 1, 0))
    pDF <- within(pDF, price <- predict(mod, newdata = pDF))
    lines(price ~ sqft, data = pDF, subset = Ind > 0, ...)
    lines(price ~ sqft, data = pDF, subset = Ind < 1, ...)
    invisible(model)
}
```

Then:

```
ylim <- range(pDF$price, DF$price)
xlim <- range(pDF$sqft, DF$sqft)
plot(price ~ sqft, data = DF, ylim = ylim, xlim = xlim)
myabline(mod, DF, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

Via the **segmented** package

```
require(segmented)
mod2 <- lm(price ~ sqft, data = DF)
mod.s <- segmented(mod2, seg.Z = ~ sqft, psi = 0.5,
                   control = seg.control(stop.if.error = FALSE))
plot(price ~ sqft, data = DF)
plot(mod.s, add = TRUE)
lines(mod.s, col = "red")
```

With these data it doesn't estimate the breakpoint at `mean(sqft)`, but the `plot` and `lines` methods in that package might help you implement something more generic than `myabline` to do this job for you diretcly from the fitted `lm()` model.

**Edit:** If you want segmented to estimate the location of the breakpoint, then set the `'psi'` argument to `NA`:

```
mod.s <- segmented(mod2, seg.Z = ~ sqft, psi = NA,
                   control = seg.control(stop.if.error = FALSE))
```

Then `segmented` will try `K = 10` quantiles of `sqft`, with `K` being set in `seg.control()` and which defaults to `10`. See `?seg.control` for more.

Comment: @Gavin (+1) Far more complete response than mine; I just like it.

Comment: @Gavin The "Via the segmented package" section didn't work for my data. I got a "No breakpoint estimated" after running the `segmented` command.

Comment: @gd047: Apologies, there was an error in the code I showed. You need to supply argument `seq.Z` with a one sided formula of the variable(s) that have a segmented relationship with the response. I've edited my answer to include `seq.Z = ~ sqft` and added a note about having `segmented` choose values of `psi` for you.

Comment: @gd047 I would like to remove my answer as this one addresses your original question in a more better way. Would mind accepting this one instead of mine?

Comment: @chl Of course, even though I still get an error : Error in if (model) objF$model <- mf : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (model) objF$model <- mf :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @gd047: Sorry, first day at work for 2 weeks and the brain isn't working. I've edited the code and it now works for me on R 2.12-patched with the latest version of segmented (0.2-7.3). This did work fine for me at home so I think I introduced errors when copying code into the answer. Check if it works now and if not, check your R and packages are up to date; Vito released a new version of the package in early December.

Comment: @gd047 The last command from @Gavin works provided we pass `model=TRUE` when calling `segmented(...)` (don't know why, even after looking at the source code of `segmented.lm`, line 104?!).

Comment: @chl: strange, both work for me without `model = TRUE`, and that is the default for this argument in `segmented`, so I wouldn't expect this to cause a problem.

Comment: @Gavin I'm on a Mac (os x 10.6) with R 2.12 and `segmented` 0.2-7.3. And yes, `model=T` is the default (didn't notice that BTW). And now, it works! Ok, found it: there was an extra `~ sqft` in your original formula.

Comment: @chl: Yes, that's right. In my first edit to fix code, I didn't see `seg.Z` explicitly, so added it not realising I had included it as an unnamed argument already. I fixed that problem with my second edit. Not sure why the first version (before all my editing) failed as it worked for me at home with up to date packages and R. My first edit was in error. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @Gavin No probs. Congrats for such a nice job and thx for the follow-up!